# Submitting form causes unknown code to appear in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I submit this form,

```
@model App.Data.ViewModels.ManageUserAccountViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Manage Account</h2>
    <hr />
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentUser.Id)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUser.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUser.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUser.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser.LastName, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUser.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUser.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser.Email, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUser.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUser.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser.UserName, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUser.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUser.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUser.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.Id)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.CurrentPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.CurrentPassword)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.NewPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.NewPassword)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.ConfirmNewPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.ConfirmNewPassword, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentUserPassword.ConfirmNewPassword)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-secondary" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

A bunch of unknown dependency items appear in my url. Im not sure whats happening. It goes away when I navigate away from the page and reload the page though.

> www.website.com/Manage?Resolver=System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver%2BCacheDependencyResolver&AsyncManager=System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncManager&ActionInvoker=System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker&HttpContext=System.Web.HttpContextWrapper&ModelState=System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary&Profile=System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile&Request=System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper&Response=System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper&RouteData=System.Web.Routing.RouteData&Server=System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper&Session=System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper&TempDataProvider=System.Web.Mvc.SessionStateTempDataProvider&Url=System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper&User=System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal&ViewEngineCollection=System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection&ControllerContext=System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext&TempData=System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary&ValidateRequest=True&ValueProvider=System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderCollection&ViewBag=System.Web.Mvc.DynamicViewDataDictionary&ViewData=System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(ManageUserAccountViewModel Input)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", Input);
        }
        UpdateUserViewModel uuvm = new UpdateUserViewModel
        {
            Id = Input.CurrentUser.Id,
            Email = Input.CurrentUser.Email,
            UserName = Input.CurrentUser.UserName,
            PhoneNumber = Input.CurrentUser.PhoneNumber,
            FirstName = Input.CurrentUser.FirstName,
            LastName = Input.CurrentUser.LastName
        };
        usersData.Update(uuvm);
        if (Input.CurrentUserPassword.CurrentPassword != null)
        {
            usersData.UpdateUserPassword(Input.CurrentUserPassword);
        }
        TempData["Success"] = "Profile "+AspNetEventLogs.Update;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", this);
    }
```

I'm not sure what I can do to remove it and haven't seen it happen anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by your

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", this);
```

where `this` is the controller (and its generating route values for its properties)

It should be just

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

or if you are wanting to pass the model to the `Index()` method, then

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", Input);
```

Comment: Why would the word this generate that huge url? Does it mean its only okay if I use it to redirect to other pages?

Comment: Because `this` is an instance of the Controller. The 2nd parameter of `RedirectToAction` is `object` and is used to generate route/query string values. It takes each property of the object and uses its `.ToString()` to generate the values for the url

Comment: I see. Thank you!